# C#/.NET how to test protected methods in singleton?

Tags: c#, testing, singleton

How to test protected methods in singleton on C#?
Is that possible?

Comment: Create a test class that subclasses your Singleton class to gain access to the protected methods and then test away!

Comment: @Bernard But it is not possible to extend Singleton because it has private constructor!

Comment: Michael Z: Dammit, you're right. Forgot about that obvious characteristic!

Comment: This does beg the question why a Singleton class has protected methods if it can never be subclassed?

Comment: @Bernard Dammit, and now you're right! :) My Singleton class has protected methods because it inherits Base class which has protected methods. And as I understand the single possible access modifier(for Singleton method) is protected here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singleton are always difficult to test, but if you want full control have a look at moles and pex. Moles enable you to test almost everything without doing any changes to the current implementation. If you really want to make testing easier, remove your global state (singleton), you probably do not need it anyway.

[moles and pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)

[singleton anti pattern](http://thetechcandy.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/singletons-is-anti-pattern/)